# Влияние package на область видимости

Tags: java, ооп

## Создаём 2 класса:

```
public class Base {
    protected void method() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }
}
```

```
public class Main extends Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base obj = new Main();
        obj.method();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем https://onlinegdb.com/ByPbAtxZP, выводит:

> Main

## Теперь разносим их в разные пакеты (больше ничего не меняем):

```
package package1;

public class Base {
    protected void method() {
        System.out.println("Base");
    }
}
```

```
package package2;

import package1.Base;

public class Main extends Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base obj = new Main();
        obj.method();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
}
```

Пытаемся скомпилировать https://onlinegdb.com/SyCsAKxWw и получаем ошибку

> ```
> Main.java:8: error: method() has protected access in Base
>       obj.method();
>          ^
> ```

## Почему после разделения на 2 пакета при попытке вызвать protected-метод базового класса происходит ошибка компиляции?

Ведь описании модификатора `protected` говорится

> Поля и методы, обозначенные модификатором доступа `protected`, будут видны:
>
> - в пределах всех классов, находящихся в том же пакете, что и наш;
> - в пределах всех классов-наследников нашего класса.

Comment: Второй пункт подразумевает не видимость метода у `Base` объектов, а видимость в `member` методах дочерних классов ( в принципе как в C++ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это кажется немного странным и объяснить это достаточно сложно. Я приведу несколько примеров, объясняющих такое поведение. Для начала сделаем так:

```
import package1.Base;

public class Main extends Base {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {        
        super.method();
        this.method();
    }

    @Override
    protected void method() {
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
    
}
```

В этом случае в консоли мы видим Base Main (сначала отрабатывает метод суперкласса, а потом класса-наследника).
Отсюда четко видно, что мы можем обратиться к protected методу родительского класса.

А теперь сделаем так:

```
import package1.Base;

public class Main extends Base {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.method();//код компилируется
        
        Base obj1 = new Main();
        obj1.method(); //ошибка компиляции
    }

    @Override
    protected void method() {
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
    
}
```

В первом случае вызов метода для Main obj = new Main() не вызывает проблем компиляции, а во втором для Base obj1 = new Main() мы видим ошибку.

Объясняется это тем, что protected метод доступен в одном пакете и для наследников (это видно в первом примере, где мы из другого пакета вызываем метод суперкласса). Во втором примере мы вызываем не метод суперкласса, а вызываем метод у переменной суперкласса (Base obj1 = new Main(); obj1.method(); - где obj1 - переменная типа суперкласса). Именно в этом кроется проблема.

Comment: Значит получается, в моём первом варианте (который компилируется) вызов доступен не из-за того, что класс является наследником, а из-за того, что они в одном пакете. А для разных пакетов можно вызывать только через super.