# Почему ругается компилятор (has protected access in ..)

Tags: java, override, protected

В одном пакете такой код:

```
package p1;
public class X {
  protected void abc (){
      System.out.println("x");
  } 
}
```

В другом:

```
package p2;
import p1.*;
public class Y extends X{
    public void abc(){
        System.out.println("Y");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new Y();
        x.abc(); // здесь ругается компилятор: abc() has protected access in X
    }
}
```

Но protected должен быть виден в Child классах, и данный метод должен выдавать "Y"

Comment: @Igor типа уровень видимости package?

Comment: Нашел такую же проблему [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159287/Влияние-package-на-область-видимости], но не понимаю, почему нельзя вызывать метод у переменной суперкласса?

Comment: Нашел ответ:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1159287/Влияние-package-на-область-видимости
Спасибо комментаторам)